# Cannot Build Apks Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

maybe this question asked previously , but when kivy is not directly available for  windows

I'm new to python and now installed all dependencies and kivy core via cmd in python , now everything is update and installed
i wrote a paint app with kivy in python , Debugged it completely and now **i want to build apk file from my source**
Unfortunately after run `buildozer android debug deploy run` command in VSCode , i got this error:

```
Unknown command/target android
```

searched all of the forums and all of github , tried all available solutions but still errors

Running : VSCode
Version: 1.41.1 (user setup)
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.14393 and latest kivy with python 3.7.4 on windows
here is my buildozer.spec:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uf6QMAGHmz2_2vuoXtI_zawdLkAmq4Jx

Comment: Some discussion here https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/812

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with buildozer (probably a minor bug), but it won't work on windows anyway.